# How to implement a SSL Client Certificate on an Apache Server for a REST api?

Tags: apache, rest, ssl, https, client-certificates

**Background:**

Imagine a website, visible to the world, **https://www.example.com**, with a static IP address, **1.1.1.1**. This site is hosted in an **Apache** server and it already possess an **SSL Server Certificate**.

On the other hand, inside a protected internal network, not visible to the world, a server (**https://www.myinternalserver.com**), with a static IP address (**2.2.2.2**), also running **Apache**, runs some internal web-based applications.

A static IP address (**3.3.3.3**), that maps to a subdomain (**myapps**) of the external site (**https://myapps.example.com**) serves as an entry point to the server where the internal web-based applications reside.

A firewall that protects the internal network does the redirect/proxying so all external traffic going to **3.3.3.3** is redirected internally to **2.2.2.2**.

The firewall also limits all external traffic so any calls going to **3.3.3.3** must have been originated at **1.1.1.1**, in essence, making the external website (**https://www.example.com**) the only authorized caller to the internal server (**https://www.myinternalserver.com**).

**Scenario**

With this infrastructure in place, I can make **REST calls** from the external website into the internal network and send back data to use in the pages. So, in this scenario, **the external site is the client** and the **internal application, the server**.

**Question:**

But beyond that, I want the server in the internal network to issue an "SSL Client Certificate" that would be "installed" (I don't know if this is the correct term), in the external website so all calls from the external site would have to be authenticated against this certificate.

How do I accomplish this?

**Breaking the question:**

I know that the question above is very broad, so let me try to break it into three (not so) "smaller" questions:

1 - **How to I create the key/certificate?** Using **OPENSSL** and some online recipes (this is one of them: **http://www.impetus.us/~rjmooney/projects/misc/clientcertauth.html**), I was able to generate the certificate file and learned (or so I believe) what I have to do with it and what to change in the **httpd.conf** file. In any case, I would like to feel more secure about what I have done so any suggestions/guidance here would be highly appreciated. For example, is the recipe I used any good?

2 - **How to "install/transfer" this certificate to the external site**? Do I simply copy/send one of the files created when generating the certificate? If so, which one? Where specifically does it go in the client server (external site)? Do they have to do anything at their end? If not, what is the process? I tried to contact the hosting company but I don't know if Icouldn't explain it to them or if they don't have experience with "SSL Client Certificate". All they told me is that there's already an SSL Certificate installed (SSL Server Certificate). They don't even seem to know what a "SSL Client Certificate" is.

3 - **Once the certificate in place, what can I do to guarantee that ALL calls to the internal server, by default, come with the Certificate, without the need to code it into each API I create?** I know very little about certificates so it might be possible that it happens "by default" always, but I read online about certificates that are "embedded" in the header of the API call, so I just want to be sure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After some more research, this is what I found...

1 - How do I create the key/certificate?

I had to try other recipes and use a combination of them to get what I wanted. What I learned is that I have to create a certificate (CA Certificate) first, and generate the Server and Client certificates based on that first one. So look for recipes that encompass all three certificates: CA, Server, Client.

2 - How to install/transfer this certificate to the external site?

Actually you simply copy the necessary ones (client/CA) to a safe place in your share of the external site. A place outside the "www" tree.

3 - Once the certificate in place, what can I do to guarantee that ALL calls...

Well, here is what I did.

I "objectified my API call using php/libcURL and place it too, outside the "www" tree. For any developer in my site to use it, all they have to do is create an instance of the object and make the call by passing the URL as a parameter. In other words, you don't install the certificate. Instead, you make a call to the certificates each time you make a call to the internal server.

I hope it helps someone out there.